# Adding a class to a <li> element that contains <strong> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-ui

I am trying to add a class to a list element, only if it consists of a `strong` element within the `li` opening and closing brackets. I feel like I'm pretty close but that I am missing something.

Here's the code that I've got so far:

```
$('.section-header__subtext ul li').each(function() {      
  if ($(this).is('strong')) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to use `children()` like - `if($(this).children().is('strong'))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `li` can't ever be `strong`, thus `$(this).is('strong')` will always be `false`, hence the CSS class is not added to the element.

You can use [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

> Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

```
$('.section-header__subtext ul li:has(strong)').addClass('selected');
```

```js
$('.section-header__subtext ul li:has(strong)').addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-header__subtext">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li><strong>2</strong></li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li><strong>4</strong></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much :) Also, thanks for the explanation of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. [jQuery find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) searches in the given element. The .length part will return the amount of elements found.

```
$('.section-header__subtext ul li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('strong').length > 0) {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.section-header__subtext ul li').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('strong').length > 0) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

Use find() method to search for elements inside of another one.